# GIT folder not seen

Tags: git

I have subccessfully installed git and was able to create a master and push the files to a remote repository. However,  I do not see the '.git' folder in my master. Is that a problem? Do I have to redo anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a folder has a dot in front of it on most systems it is hidden.

On Unix systems, you can type `ls -a` to see all files in the directory.

On Windows, `dir /a`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hidden folder. At the base of your git repo, **ls -a** will show you the folder.